# linking/version problem with libxerces-c

Tags: c++, linux, drivers, xerces-c

I am trying to make an example of a toolkit work, but after typing make, I got the following error:

```
g++ -o taskintro taskintro.o `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config orocos-ocl-gnulinux orocos-rtt-gnulinux --libs` 
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libxerces-c-3.0.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/liborocos-rtt-gnulinux.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/liborocos-rtt-gnulinux.so: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_0::XMLUni::fgXercesContinueAfterFatalError'
.
.
.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [taskintro] Error 1
```

I have the following versions installed;

```
/usr/lib/libxerces-c.so
/usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.28
/usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.28.0
/usr/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.so
```

I tried to make a symbolic linking by:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.so libxerces-c-3.0.so
```

but nothing changed. I think I need to determine the path of the installed directory but I don't have a lot experience in this issue, so I would be very happy if some one can help me to find out.

My makefile is like this;

```
*OROCOS_TARGET = gnulinux
OROPATH = /usr/local
CC = g++
LD = ld
OROFLAGS= -Wall -g `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${OROPATH}/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config orocos-ocl-${OROCOS_TARGET} orocos-rtt-${OROCOS_TARGET} --cflags` 
OROLIBS = `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${OROPATH}/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config orocos-ocl-${OROCOS_TARGET} orocos-rtt-${OROCOS_TARGET} --libs` 
all: taskintro
taskintro.o: TaskIntro.cxx ${OROPATH}/include/rtt/os/fosi.h *.hpp
    ${CC} -c ${OROFLAGS} $< -o $@*
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need Xerces 3.0, which you can download and install from http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Symbolic links to non-existing libraries is a slippery slope, but sometimes it's the easiest (or even the only) solution.

If you *have* to do this, try adding the directory containing the symbolic link to the list of directories to be searched using gcc's `-L` flag like this:

(assuming the symbolic link is in the build directory):

```
g++ -L . -o taskintro taskintro.o `...`
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to the updated question, it *should* find libxerces-c-3.0.so if it's in /usr/local/lib.

However, try this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./taskintro
```

and if it doesn't work, post the output of `ldd -v taskintro`

Also, you shouldn't need `-L` and the symbolic links anymore while compiling, now that you have installed Xerces 3.0. Please try to recompile without these.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that /usr/local/lib/liborocos-rtt-gnulinux.so is linked against the libxerces-c-3.0.so.

To see the paths where the linker goes to find the libraries, check the /etc/ld.so.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed xerces 3.0. Now it managed to compile but running the output file gives the following:

```
./taskintro: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c-3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched for the file and found it here;

```
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.0.so
```

I tried again to create a symbolic link to this file and updated the makefile as you suggested (no need for that I guess since it compiled), but nothing changed.

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.0.so libxerces-c-3.0.so

${CC} -L . -o $@ $@.o ${OROLIBS}
```

**UPDATE:**

export command helped me to compile successfully. now running the program seems to have other problems with malloc.c such as;

```
taskintro: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Checked from other forums as well, but couldn't understand what this is about. Looks like a problem with the program itself, thus have no idea how to solve it.

Gracias anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the library **libxerces-c3.0 as** your code is referring version 3.0 libraries but not any other. Use the command mentioned below to install the library.

```
 sudo apt-get install libxerces-c3.0
```